# Problems with Clearfix

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I've been having trouble applying clearfix to a number of divs, I've followed several tutorials, found [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-fudamentals-containing-children/) and [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/), but still my div named Bar will not expand to hold both the logo and nav divs.

Here is my markup, any and all advice would be greatly appreciated.
I have made the divs some strange colours to help see where they are ending and help with trying to see what is going on exactly.

```
<div id="bar" class="group">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>What We Do</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Our Work</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Our People</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" title=""    alt="" />
    </div><!--Close Logo-->
```

CSS:

```
body{
  margin:0;
}

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#bar{
  background-color: #e2871a;
  width:100%;
}

/*NAVIGATION */
#nav{
  color:#fff;
  float:right;
  margin-right:50px;
  background-color:chartreuse;
}

#nav>ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#nav>ul li{
  display:inline;
}

#nav>ul a>li {
  color:#fff;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin-right:15px;
}

#nav>ul a>li:hover{
  border-bottom:3px solid white;
} 

#logo{
  float:left;
  width:15%;
  margin-left:5%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is:

```
#nav>ul li{
   display: inline;
}
```

Top/bottom padding or margin doesn't affect the height of inline elements relative to their parent. Make it `block` or  `inline-block`

Comment: Ahh Perfect! Thank you that fixed it immediately!